# 2 PHP foreach (arrays) into one

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am currently having issues with these 2 foreach

```
$caughtpkmnfile = file ('save/' . $username . '/Pokemon.txt');
foreach ($caughtpkmnfile as $caught2) {
    $caughtpokemon2 = explode('|', $caught2);
    foreach ($caughtpokemon2 as $pkmnc){
        if ($pkmnc == ""){
            continue;
        }
        echo '<img src="pokemonsprites/' . $pkmnc . '.gif" id="pkmnc"/><p style="margin-left: 45px">' . $pkmnc . '</p> <br>';
    }
}
```

&

```
foreach (range(1, 718) as $number) {
    $pkmn2 = new \PokemonAPI\Pokemon($number);
    $pkmn = $pkmn2->getName();
    echo '<img src="pokemonsprites/' . $pkmn . '.gif" id="pkmn"/><p style="margin-left: 45px">' . $pkmn . '</p> <br>';
    ob_flush();
    flush(); //ie working must
}
```

With these two arrays, focusing on the second array, it outputs all the pokemon (images) out, and the first foreach code does the same thing but with caught pokemon (Pokemon from saved file), The output i get it
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJRc1.png), note that in .css the second code img#pkmn has no brightness in image, while first has brightness.

I am trying to make it list, in the same numeric order but if it corresponds with the caught it does id=pkmnc

not working example

```
if ($pkmn == $pkmnc){
    echo '<img src="pokemonsprites/' . $pkmnc . '.gif" id="pkmnc"/><p style="margin-left: 45px">' . $pkmnc . '</p> <br>';
        }
    else{
    echo '<img src="pokemonsprites/' . $pkmn . '.gif" id="pkmn"/><p style="margin-left: 45px">' . $pkmn . '</p> <br>';
    }
```

^^that needs to played in the foreach
In the Pokemon.txt

```
Chespin|Aron|Glalie|Luxio|Flareon|
```

Comment: If I have understood your question correctly, I would combine them both into key as first array and value as second. And using one for each i first test for $key which is first array value otherwise $value which is second array value. `$newArray = array_combine($caughtpkmnfile,$rangeArray);  foreach($newArray as $key => $value){  if($key == $value){  your first condition } else{ your second condition }  }`

Comment: Are you able to post an example of Pokemon.txt?

Comment: Ok was giving Motsim a chance to change his answer. I will post an answer.  I am going to mock the pokemon api to test, but if you are able to let me know where the api -> \PokemonAPI\Pokemon is from that would be helpful too.

Comment: @DaveThomas https://github.com/alex-phillips/PokePHP/archive/master.zip
<br>
just use `include 'src/PokemonAPI.php';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working possibility for a solution to your problem using one loop:

```
// Start question askers code
$pokemonFileContents = file_get_contents("Pokemon.txt");

foreach (range(1, 718) as $number) {
    $pkmn2 = new \PokemonAPI\Pokemon($number); 
    $pkmn = $pkmn2->getName();

    // The regex checks if it matches the name
    // with a | infront or the name with a | at the end
    //
    // Also if we have a file with no | characters it is 
    // possible to have just one pokemon name
    // this is what the or checks for
    //

    $id = "pkmn";
    if (preg_match("/(\|$pkmn)|($pkmn\|)/", $pokemonFileContents) || $pokemonFileContents == $pkmn) {

        $id .= "c";
    } 

    // I've done the if differently but there is nothing wrong
    // with doing it the other way if you feel it is more readable
    // Here I am just building up the id attribute so I can have one echo

    echo '<img src="pokemonsprites/' . $pkmn . 
        '.gif" id="'.$id.'"/><p style="margin-left: 45px">' . $pkmn . '</p> <br>'."\n";


    ob_flush();
    flush(); //ie working must
}
```

Note you must pull the file contents using file_get_contents so you have the contents as a string.

> This code is an excerpt from this Github project here:
>   https://github.com/davethomas11/stackoverflow_Q_39784013

And in case you want a solution with no regex, this would work as well:

```
$caughtpkmnfile = file ('save/' . $username . '/Pokemon.txt');
$caughtpokemon2 = [];
foreach ($caughtpkmnfile as $caught2) {
    $caughtpokemon2 = array_merge(explode('|', $caught2), $caughtpokemon2);
}

foreach (range(1, 718) as $number) {
    $pkmn2 = new \PokemonAPI\Pokemon($number); // Note: *warning I removed namespace, don't forget to put it back
    $pkmn = $pkmn2->getName();

    // The regex checks if it matches the name
    // with a | infront or the name with a | at the end
    //
    // Also if we have a file with no | characters it is
    // possible to have just one pokemon name
    // this is what the or checks for
    //

    $id = "pkmn";
    if (in_array($pkmn, $caughtpokemon2)) {

        $id .= "c";
    }

    echo '<img src="pokemonsprites/' . $pkmn .
        '.gif" id="'.$id.'"/><p style="margin-left: 45px">' . $pkmn . '</p> <br>'."\n";



    ob_flush();
    flush(); //ie working must
}
```

When benchmarked against the regex code, this code is 2x faster. Note because of the number of iterations being done it does not matter significantly.

> Using [microtime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) ->
>
> With regex run time: 0.011636 seconds
>
> With out regex run time: 0.005497 seconds

Comment: Strange, It displays blank screen.

Comment: tried checking with `echo $pkmn;` displays no variable

Comment: Did you remember to uncomment ob_flush? and I removed namespace. I'v put the question back to more resemble yours. The previous code was from my test project.

Comment: my bad didnt see that you removed the namespace for the api,
It seems to work fine, Just that the `if didn't change the id=pkmnc`

Comment: I made a mistake. None breaking naming change just made. I was calling the id a class in the variable name.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/2xqXV , I fixed the variable up but my phpstorm is saying that you might of stuffed up the `pre_match`

Comment: Oh man lol PHPstorm! Come on. I'll check it out I have a copy of IntelliJ... no issue in IntelliJ ultimate with php plugin. Downloading PHPStorm

Comment: Odd PHPStorm is flagging it as an unknown character: http://imgur.com/a/7NtQS   What it actually is escaping the pipe character so we can match against it. You have to escape the pipe in a regular expression because it is a character that has meaning. As far as I can see from executions of the code I posted on Github it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question correctly, I would combine them both into key as first array and value as second. And using one for each i first test for $key which is first array value otherwise $value which is second array value.

```
   $caughtpokemon2 = array();
   foreach($caughtpkmnfile as $caught2){
   $splitted = explode('|', $caught2);
   array_push($caughtpokemon2,$spliited);
  } 
    foreach($rangeArray as $pkmn)
    {  
    if(in_array($pkmn,$pkmnc)){  //If $pkmn value exists in $pkmnc
     //Find Index of value
       $index = array_search($pkmn,$pkmnc,true);
     echo '<img src="pokemonsprites/' . $pkmnc[$index ]. '.gif" id="pkmnc"/><p     style="margin-left: 45px">' . $pkmnc[$index ]. '</p> <br>';
     } 
    else{
     echo '<img src="pokemonsprites/' . $pkmn. '.gif" id="pkmn"/><p style="margin-left: 45px">' . $pkmn. '</p> <br>';
     }  
    }
```

Comment: Motsim, double check that. Chance contents of $caughtpkmnfile is not what you expect. ;)  Notice that it is being split again via the | character

Comment: the file in the content is Chespin|Aron|Glalie|Luxio|Flareon|

Comment: Your welcome! Here is what I suggest we try; Let's assume the contents of Pokemon.txt.  Maybe it could be something like:  rock|paper|cat. Possibility of multiple lines based on the code. If we put the contents of that file in a string. We could in one loop through 1 to 712 check the existence of that name in the string?

Comment: array_combine is the next spot you are making a mistake. Make sure you run your code to test it!

Comment: I copied in the code it went blanked, *I think because $rangeArray is underdefined and I'm using a api which changes NUMBERS -> Pokemon name
`$pkmn2 = new \PokemonAPI\Pokemon($number);
    $pkmn = $pkmn2->getName();`

Comment: yeah i don't really know about the api and may be i understood your question wrong. I was just working on the method not the api by the way